# PHP if statement not displaying HTML

Tags: php, html, if-statement

So I'm checking if a user is logged in, and if so I'll remove the signup forms. So I thought I'd do it with if else statements. So here's my code

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedin'] === false): ?>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<?php elseif($_SESSION['loggedin'] === true):?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

For some reason all I get is a blank page. I'm using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

To display errors, but I'm not getting anything. On another page when doing a `var_dump` on `$_SESSION['loggedin'` I get `bool(true)`, so I know that I'm logged in and expect `Welcome`. I feel like its a syntax error. 
Any ideas?

Comment: session_start(); have you put this on the top just after <?php

Comment: Check your apache (or whatever webserver) error logs, maybe you're having an error you can't see with display_errors?

Comment: I am using `session_start()`, its in another `<?php` tag right at the top @MehulMohan

Comment: Try adding an `isset()` to your if test.

Comment: Change your else line to: `<?php else:?>` to troubleshoot. Looks like `loggedin` is neither false nor true.

Comment: use `if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))`instead `=== false`, `$_SESSION['loggedin']` was not set, so its null, not false.

Comment: @joaofgf what if it is set and set to false? You have to have an `||` also.

Comment: @Pitchinnate yes, its true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tail your server logs (e.g. `tail -F logs/php_error.log`) you'll probably see something like:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION

Try changing the code to:

```
if (isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true )
{
  echo 'Welcome';
} else {
  echo 'Sign up';
}
```

Personally I'd also recommend changing your sign out logic to use `unset($_SESSION)` that way you only have to check for:

```
if (isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) ){
  echo 'Welcome';
} else {
  echo 'Sign up';
}
```

Comment: What happens if there is session info that should persist despite login state? Not saying there is in this case but there could be.

Comment: I have sites which require that - in that case I name space everything inside the session e.g. $_SESSION['user']['id'], $_SESSION['user']['name'] etc... Then during logout you can just call unset($_SESSION['user']) and check using if (isset($_SESSION['user']))

Comment: Correct, I was just putting out a word of caution. In this case they could just use `unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true): ?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php else:?>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I agree. Geting rid of the `elseif` statement will help, plus the `isset()` check.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that neither code path gets executed if `$_SESSION['loggedin']` isn't a boolean because the `===` comparison checks *type* and value.  (See [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for details)

A more safe and sane approach would be:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedin'] === true): ?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php else:?>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `isset()` to your if test.

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] === false): ?>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<?php else: ?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<?php if(!$_SESSION['loggedin']) { ?>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<?php } elseif($_SESSION['loggedin']) { ?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not resulting due to  `Undefined variable: _SESSION` error. so you can utilize any ignorant (@ or &) Ex. `@$_SESSION['loggedin']` OR `&$_SESSION['loggedin']`